# Xml to js code problem

Tags: javascript, xml

So i'm very new to xml to javascript so i thought I would learn from w3schools, but this site 
http://www.w3schools.com/xml/xml_to_html.asp shows an example that I can't mimic locally. I copy/pasted the .js and downloaded the xml but I just get a blank screen!

It's working in there try it yourself but not for me? Do I need it on a server or something?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that code retrieves the XML data from a web server using AJAX. Since you don't have a server running locally, you can change the URL to point directly to the w3school's version:

```
xmlhttp.open("GET","http://www.w3schools.com/xml/cd_catalog.xml",false);
```

Alternatively, play around on their [online version](http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tryit.asp?filename=tryxml_display_table) ;)

Answer (score 0):

well i guess  you have to add the example xml (cd_catalog.xml) to your file system. and you definitively have to access the html file on a server (apache i.e.)

Answer (score 0):

First, ensure that both HTML file (with the Javascript block in it) and XML file are placed in the same directory.

Next, you probably need to place those files under your local web-server and open the HTML like this:

```
http://[local server host]/ajax.html
```

instead of opening the file directly from e.g. Windows Explorer:

```
C:\[path to the file]\ajax.html
```

For the latter case you'll get an "Access is denied" error.

-- Pavel

Answer (score 0):

Are you running this under a web server or just creating a couple of text files and loading them in your browser?

The "GET" request this relies upon could possibly be failing.

Use Apache or another similar HTTP server and run the example as if it were hosted on the web.